# Java- In Eclipse everything is fine but after building- "Can't read input file!"

Tags: java, eclipse

This is my first question here and probably it is too cliche to answer, but I hope for the best.
I made an app, which reads  .gif files from /bin folder using ImageIO.read. 
In code, there is:

```
File imageFile = new File("bin/logo.gif");
```

and everything works fine, but after compiling th eapp and running it from .jar file, there is an error "Can't read input file!". I had this problem inside Eclipse, so I wrote "/bin" in the file reading path.

What should I do?

Comment: Is the logo.gif file in the given path and what about directory/file access rights?

Comment: I think when you build the project the bin folder is cleared, so your file logi.gif as well.

Comment: Of course I tried it. I made a bin folder inside jar file and copied all gifs. It doesn't work.

Comment: /bin is only for read but files existing in it have all rights. Actually, I cannot make this read-only option stay unchecked. Can this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the `.gif` files in the bin is not a good option. It is a better approach to make a separate folder (For example, `/images`) in your `/src` directory and access your resource files from there.

Comment: Actually, the problem stays the same. I'm positive that there is a /images/logo.gif file in the .jar (because I copied it there after building in Eclipse). When running in Eclipse, there is no problem. Also, I wonder: if  I'll give the full path: setSpriteName("F:/Workspace/ArkanoidInvaders/images/gracz.gif");  the compiller will search for the "gracz.gif" in the ".jar/images/" ?  I don't know how to go "up" in the folder tree when in this code: setSpriteName("gracz.gif"); Eclipse (or setSpriteName?) in default is searching for the file in F:/Workspace/ArkanoidInvaders/bin folder

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer: File gets the image from the catalogue in which is the .jar file. setSpriteName gets images from catalogues inside .jar file.